# VBA Excel to Word paste includes new line after pasted text

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to paste a cell's text to a bookmarked place on a word doc. When I do this it adds a new line after the newly pasted text. How do I get rid of this? I'm using the

```
PasteAndFormat (wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

> ```
> Txt = "My cell value as string"
> With ActiveDocument
>     .Bookmarks("Mark").Range.Text = Txt
> End With
> ```

The bookmark will be over-written and can't be used again. If you need to preserve it, capture the range containing the new text and reset the bookmark pointing at it.